# How interface counters in cisco 2960s works?

Tags: networking, cisco

Do input/output rate counters include packet header length?

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/22 is up, line protocol is up (connected)<br>
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 2037.0695.d796 (bia 2037.0695.d796)<br>
  Description: none<br>
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000 Kbit, DLY 1000 usec,<br>
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255<br>
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set<br>
  Keepalive set (10 sec)<br>
  Full-duplex, 10Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX<br>
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported<br>
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00<br>
  Last input never, output 00:00:00, output hang never<br>
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 4d19h<br>
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0<br>
  Queueing strategy: fifo<br>
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)<br>
  5 minute input rate **6000 bits/sec**, 10 packets/sec<br>
  5 minute output rate **8000 bits/sec**, 12 packets/sec<br>
     4925456 packets input, 357515262 bytes, 0 no buffer<br>
     Received 33 broadcasts (0 multicasts)<br>
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles<br>
     168 input errors, 168 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored<br>
     0 watchdog, 0 multicast, 0 pause input<br>
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected<br>
     6094670 packets output, 492552863 bytes, 0 underruns<br>
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets<br>
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred<br>
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output<br>
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2960 is a L2 Switch with some limited L3 capabilities. Since your using a L2 interface It should include the header. (L3 wont)